# Output render looks grainy and pixely even though samples are high

Tags: rendering, texturing, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, light

The samples in the rendered picture are set to 12, I tried setting them to 20 and it made no difference. I don't understand why, but this is the only object in my scene that has this weird lighting (the actual room itself).
[image]

[image]

Comment: 20 samples is not very high. Make sure you dont have square samples check on. Then push the samples to maybe a couple hundred. Make sure your light source is large enough. I would need to see your render settings to know for sure.